# How to detect an active VPN connection with a specific name

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, vpn, windows-server-2008-r2

I found an [article](https://smsagent.wordpress.com/2016/06/10/detect-an-active-vpn-adapter-during-configmgr-deployments/) which lists several ways to detect an active VPN:

1. Using Win32_NetworkAdapter:

   ```
   Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter 
   where Name like '%VPN%' and NetEnabled='True'"
   ```
2. Using Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration:

   ```
   Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration 
   where Description like '%VPN%' and IPEnabled='True'"
   ```
3. Checking the presence of an active PPP adapter

   ```
   ipconfig | Select-String 'PPP adapter'
   ```
4. Checking the IPv4 routing table

   ```
   Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_IP4RouteTable 
   where Name like '10.0.99.%' or Name like '10.15.99.%'"
   ```

In my case approaches 1,2 & 4 simply didn't work. The third approach works well and it's really enough. But as far as I understand having multiple VPN connections configured can give an ambiguous result for method 3.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to be more specific (use combined approach maybe?) with method 3, to be able to check the connection name?
2. Why didn't methods 1 & 2 work for me? Querying it like this

   ```
   $adapters = (Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter")
   foreach($a in $adapters) {
       Write-Host $a.Description
   }
   ```

   gives me a list of adapter names with no mention of 'VPN' in their description:

   ```
   WAN Miniport (SSTP)
   WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
   WAN Miniport (L2TP)
   WAN Miniport (PPTP)
   and so on...
   ```

Comment: well, can you check the output of `ipconfig` on a PC with 2 active VPN connections to discern if they differ somehow and filter based on that? at the very worst you will get `ppp adapter` 2 times, but I'm sure they will differ and you can work out a way to filter stuff

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way will be to use the Powershell Commamdlet

```
Get-VPNconnection -Name "VPN Name"
```

One of the items reported is "ConnectionStatus". Also if the VPN is an All user connection you will also have to use the switch "-AllUserConnection" with the commandlet

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with all VPNs. I just tried while connected to Fortinet VPN (FortiClient) and got no results from Get-VPNconnection

Answer (score 2):

How about using this:

```
Get-NetAdapter -InterfaceDescription "VPN Name" | where {$_.status -eq "Up"}
```

Just Use `Get-NetAdapter` to get a list of the Network/VPN Names..

Answer (score 2):

In my scenario, the presence of `TAP` in the `InterfaceDescription` property signifies the VPN connection status, but you could put any string within the test

```
$NIC = Get-NetIPConfiguration | ? {$_.NetAdapter.status -eq "UP"} | Select-Object InterfaceDescription
    if ($NIC -match "TAP") {
#VPN active → go to work
} else { 
       Write-Host "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" -ForegroundColor Cyan 
       Write-Host "VPN DEACTIVATED ?" -ForegroundColor Cyan 
       Write-Host "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" -ForegroundColor Cyan 
    }
```

Comment: You are searching the whole filtered object for `TAP`. If you want to search only `InterfaceDescription`, you should do `Select-Object -expandproperty InterfaceDescription` per https://stackoverflow.com/a/41434612/11464478

Comment: Agreed, it is a bit cleaner, but don't think it makes that much of a difference, does it? It is still just a single NoteProperty, right? Just FYI, the official docs on `-ExpandProperty` → https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2#parameters

Comment: I found this because I needed `-eq` because VPN interface was substring of other interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to get the PPP-adapter and other hidden adapter info you should use this:

```
[System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface]::GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
```